# Undo conflicted pull request in TFS

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, request, undo

We are using TFS for managing code, and its online application. There's a pull request created for one of the branches (feature/111222-feature-name-blabla). I did a mistake and pushed "Complete pull request" in the online application, but I should have not. The merge has conflicts, so it has not been merged to develop branch. Is it a way to undo it? so set the pull request to the previous state, and ignore all the changes?

Answer (score 1):

You could choose **Abandon** to close the pull request without merging the changes.